# changing .../details?id=xxx in android market with upgrade?

Tags: android, google-play

is it possible to change the id (in this case xxx) in the url https://market.android.com/details?id=xxx for one app only with an update?
For example to https://market.android.com/details?id=aaa.
Or is it realy necessary to upload it as an new app  to achieve this?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to rename the Package Name of your App to change this ID, but then it's actually a new App and you have to upload it as a new App.

See also: [How to change package name of an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application/4025633#4025633)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Do you also know if it is possible to delete the actuall one and upload a new App **with the same name** as the deleted (but another id)? For iPhone this is not possible, is it for android?

Comment: Yes, afaik this should be possible.