# android development - smart way to have both the current published version and the development version on my device

Tags: android

I guess this could be a common problem for new android developer like myself so I thought to ask it even so it is not a big deal. 
I would like to have both the current published stable version of an app and the under development version on my device. Yet when I want to install both I get

```
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
You must perform a full uninstall of the application.
```

I understand it technically yet I was wondering how I could have an easy way around this so I can have both application on my phone. I could change the package name for the time being but I hope there is an even more straight forward way to get it done.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Solution as given by "Marc Bernstein" in the following post - thx Algo for posting the link to it

[How to change package name of an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application/9171773#9171773)

There is a way to change the package name easily in Eclipse. Right click on your project, scroll down to Android Tools, and then click on Rename Application Package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change package name of your published and development version Application. Changing Package name is really very simple and easy, follow that post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171773/185022

Comment: thx a lot - didnt see the "Android Tool->change package name" one before - very simple as you said

Answer (score 1):

The "published" version should be signed using a release keystore.

The "development" version should be signed using a debug keystore.

At installation time, Android will complain that the two applications (having the same package name) have **different signatures**, and won't install the latest one (`Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.`).

To fix this (**normal**) behavior, **change the package name** of your application while developing it (ex: com.example.myapp-dev).

Comment: thx - as mentioned i understand the technical reason behind. changing package name is of course possible, yes as this is just what everybody needs i hope eclipse/android has something more elegant ...