# Easy way to change package name

Tags: android, package, project

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Package renaming in eclipse android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697899/package-renaming-in-eclipse-android-project)

Is there a easy way to change the package name of an android project? When I change it in manifest from xxx.en to xxx.zh, I need to fix all "import xxx.en.R" to "import xxx.zh.R" in every java files! plz help me, a easy way is needed.

Comment: if your using eclipse, right click on the package, then click refactor, then Rename. It will update all its references. for shortcut click on the package then press Alt+Shift+R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using eclipse,
3 steps:

1) change in manifest

2) select project in navigator and press clt+h. Search from string 
import xxx.en.R;     In search tab you will get full list of string matches.

3) Right click any of the match and select replace all , enter the replace text as "import xxx.zh.R;"

Hit enter and its done.

Answer (score 5):

You can try by: `right click on your project > Android Tools > Rename Application Package`. I think this link is useful for you: [How to change package name of an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application)

Comment: It is the better way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

1. In the manifest file, instead of the old package name, put the new package name at every location
   Your classes may need direct package name references like activity android:name="com.abc.Myactivity".
2. Right click the package name inside the project. Select Refactor>Rename and type the desired new package name. select "update references".
3. Change the layout xml files with the new package name

Answer (score 1):

**It is very easy
Just click on package which you want to change name than press F2 key it will show warning than press ok than rename package.**

com.****.*****

after press F2

Com.####.*****