# The import com.company.projectname.R cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing an application for the company I work for and I am running into an issue with Eclipse. I've been looking online all over and I cannot seem to find a fix for this specific issue. I have changed `import android.R;` to `import com.company.projectname.R;` however I get the error "The import com.company.projectname.R cannot be resolved" obviously I replaced company and projectname with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what the imports should look like:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar;
```

Notice I don't import com.company.projectname.R; Make sure your sdk is updated... After you have done that clean the project.. And rebuild it. You should be fine :D

-Monkey

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that the SDK didn't install all the packages that I selected. :S

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the project, sometimes clean my projects have solved my problems on Eclipse/Android.

If it doesn't work, you can see there if it corresponds with what you did:
[Question like yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application)

Comment: Edited my post to add a link, verify the answer with your demarch