# How can I change Application name, project name, package name, and its icon?

Tags: android

I do have an existing project.
I want to change its

1. Application name
2. Project name
3. Package name
4. Icon

Is it possible to set them up again?
I use Eclipse for IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For changing:

**App Name:**

Go to `res->values->string.xml` -> Change appname

**App Icon:**

Go to Android manifest -> `android:icon = "@drawble/yourIcon"`

**Package Name:**

In Eclipse, Right click on your project `Android Tools->Rename Application Packege`. For detail follow this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application?rq=1)

**Project Name:**

Select your project, go to `File Menu -> Rename or Press F2`.

Answer (score 2):

1-The app name is stored in string.xml file in `value` folder. You can change the xml file.

2-Just right click on the project click `refactor -> rename`.

3-[How to change package name of an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application?rq=1)

4- Your Icon is sotred in `res -> drawable` folder in your project.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in Application tag file manifest

```
android:icon="your icon"
android:label="application name"
```

for change package you can right click on package and refactor->rename

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Eclipse, the easiest is to create a new project and copy over all the relevant sources and resources. (Leave the old icons behind if you're creating new ones.) I've found that trying to make those changes to an existing project tends to leave several loose ends that are hard to track down.

Comment: That's a far cry from "the easiest".

Comment: @323go - It's actually very easy. I've done it several times (usually as a way to start a new project based on an old one) and it takes about a minute. It's just copy-and-paste of a few nodes from one project tree to the other in the Eclipse package explorer.