# How to change package directory of a android application

Tags: android

hi just want to ask how to change application directory package folder name.
Example is `com.old.here` to `com.new.here` i already recompile the app but nothing happen. I already change manifest still nothing happen he still install with the old folder name. 
i need to change it to new one. please mail me if someone can do it for me.

this is what i want to change

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uoBn.jpg   folder name  where when you install the application it will create the folder i want

Comment: please see the answer of below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application

its better to search for your problems their are many questions already asked for this issue.

Comment: Change the name of package on the IDE, compile, uninstall your app and after install.

Comment: The folder name under /data/data is the fully qualified package name. If you want to change it then change your package name as others have suggested. Make sure you've uninstalled the old version of the app first though - doing that will delete the current /data/data package folder.

Comment: @user3714486 Every answer and comment on this question have correct methods of doing what you need to do. Please follow the directions and you will be pleasantly surprised - I am under the impression you are confused about exactly what the folder name is. To reiterate again, it is the package name, as stated above in the comments and below in answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Android studio**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) is the good answer.

1. First make sure you are viewing the project in Android view.
2. Now click on setting gear icon and deselect Compact Empty Middle Package
3. refactor any folder.

To change application go to app gradle file and change applicationId.

**Eclipse**

1. change package name in manifest
2. go to src of your project and right click on package name,select refactor then rename package name.

Comment: what tool should i use? can you name it?

Comment: are you not using eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

This link should provide some knowledge on changing the package name: [How to change package name of an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application)

It seems fairly easy to do and just requires updating the Android Manifest.

EDIT:

From the same question, this seems like the most direct way, although it is not the accepted answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025633/3662013

Comment: i need folder change sir.. not the name of the application :(

Comment: What do you mean folder? By changing the package name, the name of the application will not change.

Comment: Looking at your edit @user3714486 with the picture included, following the steps in this question will change that folder name. That is the package name, which is a collection of all your project files