# creating new app by modifying another app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to create a new app by modifying code of an existing app's source code. So I did the following from eclipse:

1. exported the code of the old app "app1" to a file system.
2. created a new Java project "app2", and imported the code that was exported earlier.
3. modified strings.xml, and renamed the app_name as "app2"
4. made other edits to app2's code, for a new feature.
5. ran app2 on the mobile device (connected to the PC)

Now app2 is working correctly, and its name is also seen as "app2". But I see that when I loaded the code onto the mobile device, **it has replaced the app1 that was previously installed**, ie the app1 is no more visible on the device.

So my question is: what other changes do I need to make (apart from the strings.xml:app_name) to make a completely new app? ie, I want both app1 and app2 to exist on the device.

Comment: You also need to change the package name in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Choose a different package name for the Java source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change package name as package name plays as unique in android.

Here is showing way how to do that :

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025422/4161269